# readLine use in TabBar App

Tags: ios, swift, input, readline

im writing an App For my Dad's Office and it's about Finding the Monthly Revenues. It has a very simple UI and Now im staring writing the code. I know the command:

```
import Foundation

print("What is your name? ")
if let yourName = readLine() {
print("Hello, \(yourName)")
}
```

But as I know and tested, I can use it only in a Command Application For Mac's.

Just to explain what I want to do.  The program just asks the user to write the every day  Revenues. It prints the :

```
print("Write The Revenues Of This Day:")
```

Then, I have thought that with this command, the user could write the Amount Of Money, and sum the numbers and find the Monthly Revenue. But as this command doesn't work in IOS devices, what can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users won't have access to a terminal. You will need to use UI widget, like, for instance, `UITextField` to enter text.

Then, you will need to store that, perhaps calling a backend server running a db, or something like that.

For the "capture text on the iPhone" part, take a look at [this](https://github.com/volonbolon/friendly-happiness)

Comment: Thank you soo much! Code in GitHub helped me a lot! I'll try to test it in the next hours.  Something else. Can you tell me a possible solution to the EDIT that i wrote in my question please? I know how to loop days from 1 to 30 but i dont know how to display them. I want something like: print("Enter the revenues of day \(day)")  and the \(day) will be the loop. But how can i dispay with loop the days? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of now, you can't write command line applications on iOS. So you'll have to learn how to make an iOS app and understand concepts like views, view controllers, UI elements such as textfields... in order to make the app you want to do.

Here is a [starting point](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/).

Comment: I already know exactly how to make an App. And to Code. I don't know how to add and which command to ask the user to type the Money. I have write the basic command but it's not working on IOS. Some further help please?

Comment: You don't understand the structure of an app in iOS. There is no *commands* because no command line applications, just **UI elements showing information to the user** or **getting information from the user** that you can manipulate from view controllers for example.

Comment: So, you suggest me to find in a UI element something that may says "input" or something like that, right?

Comment: Yes, a **UITextField** for example.

Comment: Οκ. I will search it tommorow. (Becauae its night here.) Thanks